# Какие функции из библиотеки string можно добавить?

Tags: c, строки, сортировка

Стояла задача:Дана строка символов. Найти в строке самое длинное слово и вывести его на экран. Код написал и все работает, только вот практик сказал добавить еще функций из библиотеки string, а при надобности вообще переписать код.. Посмотрел все функции из библиотеки и самой нужной воспользовался. Можно ли с помощью других сделать какую-нибудь проверку или вовсе добавить незначительную деталь с использованием функции из string?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
   char s[1024];
   int sm = 0, lm = 1, bs = 0, bl = 0;
   printf("Введите строку символов: ");
   gets(s);
   for (int i = 0; i < sizestrlen(s) + 1; i++) {
       if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\0') {
           bl = i;
           if (bl - bs > lm - sm) {
               sm = bs;
               lm = bl;
           }
           bs = i + 1;
       }
   }
   printf("Самое длинное слово - ");
   for (int i = sm; i < lm; i++) {
       printf("%c", s[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: strtok выполнит значительную часть работы

Comment: что он делает и какую часть работы он может выполнить?

Comment: Это неcекретная информация, её можно прочитать

Comment: @MBo поэтому решил спросить сразу Вас

Comment: @Mbo посмотрел что именно делает эта функция и не придумал применения у себя в программе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Online](https://onlinegdb.com/t44-W5rE83)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
   char str[] = "съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю";
   char lw[100]; 
   char *pw = strtok(str, " ,.");
   int maxl = 0;
   int slen;
   while (pw != NULL)  {
      slen = strlen(pw);
      if (slen > maxl) {
          maxl = slen;
          strcpy(lw, pw);
      }
      pw = strtok(NULL, " ,.");
    }
    printf("%s", lw);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добавил к вашему коду возможность ввода строки в массив str и ввел "булочка стоит 100000000". Вывело, что самое длинное слово булочка. так же будет, если ввести одно слово и число, второе программа просто игнорирует. может это из-за strtoka как-раз?

Comment: не игнорирует, дело в юникоде, руccкие буквы занимают два байта. если сделать число вдвое длиннее - оно выберется. Как правильно в символах в С длину считать - не в курсе

Comment: Считать символы в [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) очень просто. Если `(str[i] & 0xC0) != 0x80`, то это первый байт символа в utf-8. Просто бегите по строке и подсчитывайте количество

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй isLetter или что-то в этом роде (не помню точное название) для определения пробелов - расскажи практику, что предотвращаешь пробелы в начале строки и двойные пробелы в середине

Comment: он входит в список функций string?